# Error: CLI0115E Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, db2

I'm trying to execute an SQL Server stored procedure using the execute SQL task of an SSIS package and I'm getting errors.

> CLI0115E  Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000
>
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "xxx.xxx" for linked
>   server "xxxxx".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

The stored procedure inserts data to a temp table and it contains a query with a join to db2 server. I'm using OPENQUERY to connect to the db2 database.

Example:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from OPENQUERY(@databasename,'select col1, col2, col3 from db2table1 where col3=xx') as qry1
join sqltable1 on qr1.col1 = sqltable1=col1
```

The SSIS package is supposed to run in loops and each time the stored procedure is supposed to return nearly 500 records. The error happens intermittently and doesn't occur when the stored procedure is run manually using SQL Server Management studio.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an error in the DB2 code.  Someone who has visibility into that code needs to debug it.

Comment: if you are executing this SP using ExecuteSQL task, then display the value of Execute SQL task Editor.